# Comparing array values with mysqli result

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, mysqli

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Below code i used in an edit page, and i want to compare the checkbox values and if it is matching make it as checked.

Example of my two array values

```
$CategoryDetails : Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 1 )
$Category_data : Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 6 [3] => 2 [4] => 4 [5] => 7)
```

`$Category_data` is am using to create checkbox and `$CategoryDetails` is the selected values. So as per above eg checkbox 1 & 3 should be checked, but below code giving me only one checked ie. checkbox3

I need to compare each value of array1 with array2.

```
<?php
    $CategoryDetails = isset($category_list) ? $category_list : ' ';
    $Category = dbSelectByWhere("Highlight_categories", "WHERE Highlight_cat_status=1", "Order By Highlight_Category_name");
    $k = 0;
    while ($Category_data = dbFetchArray($Category)) {
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="Category" value="<?php echo $Category_data['Highlight_category_id']; ?>" data-parsley-mincheck="1" required class="flat" <?php
        if (isset($CategoryDetails) && ($CategoryDetails[$k] == $Category_data['Highlight_category_id'])) {
            echo 'checked';
            if ($k < (count($CategoryDetails) - 1)) {
                $k++;
            }
        }
        ?>/> <?php echo $Category_data['Highlight_Category_name']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st :** You need to use **in_array** function.

**2nd :** in_array function searches an array for a specific value .if value exists it will return true else it will return false .

**3rd :** If empty declare the variable as array

```
$CategoryDetails = isset($category_list) ? $category_list : array();
```

PHP :

```
while ($Category_data = dbFetchArray($Category)) {
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="Category" value="<?php echo $Category_data['Highlight_category_id']; ?>" data-parsley-mincheck="1" required class="flat" <?php
        if (isset($CategoryDetails) && in_array($Category_data['Highlight_category_id'],$CategoryDetails)) {
            echo 'checked';
        }
        ?>/> <?php echo $Category_data['Highlight_Category_name']; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Think it should be `$CategoryDetails = isset($category_list) ? $category_list : array();`